# Nintex Custom Set a Condition Action

Tags: workflow

Using Nintex Workflow, I know how to create a custom action that simply executes without passing around data.  But how do I create a custom "Set a Condition" action?  In particular, I want to know how to communicate the result of the action (true or false) back to the workflow so that the appropriate branch can be taken.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is wondering, the workaround was to have the custom action write its result to a Boolean workflow variable, and then to check the value of that variable from the out-of-the-box "Set a Condition" action.  Nintex SDK has details on writing to an existing workflow variable from a custom action.